# How to replace a string in powershell?

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I need to extricate the file extension from the file paths.
For Eg: I have a file path like:

```
\\Test\data\data.dll
```

How to remove the data.dll from the file path, so that I get only

```
\\Test\data\
```

as the output.

I tried using the wild character - *. but that didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case there is a special cmdlet that by default removes the file or folder at the end. Try:

```
$path =  \\test\data\data.dll
#Get folderpath    
Split-Path $path
#Get filename only (thanks to Christian for tip)
Split-Path $path -Leaf
```

Comment: Graimer: What if I want to do it vise versa.. i.e, How do I get only the data.dll and not the path before that??

Comment: Test the updated answer. If it doesn't work, tell me and I'll fix it in 30min when I get a computer :)

Comment: @ashishg For just the file name: `Split-Path \\test\data\data.dll -Leaf`

Comment: there, thanks for tip Christian. Cleaned up answer to include it now :)

Comment: Ya it works.. Thanks Graimer:) Graimer just refering to previous question could you tell me how wud I read the DLLs and PDBs if I had multiple sorces. For Eg: .\Projects\, .\Data\ etc

Answer (score 0):

Here's 2 different ways of doing it.  One is to use Split-Path.  The other is to use -replace with regular expressions.  They both work great in PowerShell V3, but Split-Path doesn't work in V2 if the path has a drive letter in it, but your system doesn't have that drive letter.

```
#Get Folder
Split-Path '\\test\data\data.dll'
'\\test\data\data.dll' -replace '\\[^\\]+$'

#Get File 
Split-Path '\\test\data\data.dll' -Leaf
'\\test\data\data.dll' -replace '^\\.*\\'
```

Comment: Make sure you use a drive letter you don't have on your system, ie J:.  You can then do the following to see the problem. `Split-Path 'J:\data\data.dll'` You'll get the error message: "Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'J' does not exist."I reported this to them a long time ago on connect.microsoft.com, but it wasn't fixed until V3. [link](https://connect.microsoft.com/PowerShell/feedback/details/499194)

Comment: thanks for the info. You should add this in your answer. Not many people need to split-path for a non existing drive ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add my 2 cents for a workaround for the issue told by @StephenMills in his answer:

```
PS C:\ps> ( [system.io.fileinfo]"J:\data\data.dll" ).FullName
J:\data\data.dll
PS C:\ps> ( [system.io.fileinfo]"J:\data\data.dll" ).BaseName
data
PS C:\ps> ( [system.io.fileinfo]"J:\data\data.dll" ).name
data.dll
PS C:\ps> ( [system.io.fileinfo]"J:\data\data.dll" ).DirectoryName
J:\data
```